# convert raw to long in R?

Tags: r

I need to read a binary file which encodes longs. I give just one of the longs as an example.

```
# don't know a simpler way to create the raw vector
z <- writeBin(c(8L, 208L, 59L, 233L, 106L, 151L, 126L, 73L), raw())
dim(z) <- c(4,8)
z1 <- z[1,]
#[1] 08 d0 3b e9 6a 97 7e 49
```

The vector z1 is in binary (e.g. http://www.asciitohex.com/):

00001000 11010000 00111011 11101001 01101010 10010111 01111110 01001001

which is in decimal (java.lang.Long.parseLong( v,2)):

635073421160971849

```
> readBin(z1, what="integer", size=8, n=1 )
[1] -381956088
> readBin(z1, what="integer", size=8, n=1, endian="big")
[1] 1788313161
#etc...
```

Which is not what I want.
How do I do the conversion from the raw vector in R?

Comment: R doesn't have a long data type, only double and 32-bit integer. The [int64](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/int64/) and [bit64](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bit64/) packages have some 64-bit integer support, but it doesn't look like they handle conversion from raw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you can do this with the [gmp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gmp/index.html) package, if you convert your raw vector into a character format.  I used hex in the example below.

```
#install.packages("gmp")
library(gmp)
as.bigz(paste0("0x",paste0(as.character(z1),collapse="")))
# Big Integer ('bigz') :
# [1] 635073421160971849
```

Answer (score 3):

This is hackish and unstraightforward and foolish and all that, but since I also think it's interesting, I couldn't resist trying. And since I tried, I'm going to post it.

Joshua is right in that `int64` doesn't support conversion from `raw`. However, it just stores each 64-bit integer as two 32-bit integers, so you could convert your `raw` to an `int64` by splitting it into two and reading each piece as an integer:

```
> my.long <- int64(1)
> my.long@.Data[[1]] <- c(readBin(z1[1:4], what="integer", endian="big"), readBin(z1[5:8], what="integer", endian="big"))
> my.long
[1] 635073421160971849
```

Comment: Very nice, but the int64 package feels like a dead end, because its orphaned and it seems like I can get the data out only with @.Data[[1]] and cant divide it and convert it to double.

Comment: @IdoTamir: I contacted the maintainer of int64 and he is contacting CRAN to understand why the package was listed as orphaned.

Comment: @IdoTamir, only if you're interested in the two 32-bit integers, which you only would need to worry about during creation. Otherwise, you can access the 64-bit integer (or integer*s*, since you can think of it as a vector) with, in my example, `my.long`. You can do division on this, but it doesn't look like it can be easily converted to a double. This is hypothetical though; personally I don't know that I would use this approach, since relying on or abusing the internal representation of an object doesn't seem right to me.