# Converting hex string to a 64-bit integer/timestamp using R

Tags: r, 64-bit

I need to read 8 bytes in from a binary file and convert it to a timestamp.  Getting the data into a character array is not hard.  I end up with

```
DateTime <- as.raw(c(0x11, 0x77, 0x84, 0x43, 0xe6, 0x11, 0xd8, 0x08))
```

The data format is endian="little" so if I reverse this array I can get a string which represents the number in hex

```
paste(rev(DateTime),collapse="")
```

which yields "08d811e643847711"

Using the bit64 package, I would like to be able to use this

```
x <- as.integer64(0x8d811e643847711)
```

but I cannot figure out how to get the string above to be used as an argument to as.integer64.  Ie, this generates an error (well, an NA.  Not the number ...):

```
x <- as.integer64(paste(rev(DateTime),collapse=""))
```

Can anyone point me to a solution?
TIA,
mconsidine

Comment: Maybe related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432916/convert-raw-to-long-in-r

Comment: Thanks.  What I came up with is posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your hexadecimal number is positive (uppermost bit not set):

```
require(bit64)

DateTime <- as.raw(c(0x11, 0x77, 0x84, 0x43, 0xe6, 0x11, 0xd8, 0x08))

x <- as.integer64('0')
x <- 256 * x + as.integer(DateTime[1])
x <- 256 * x + as.integer(DateTime[2])
x <- 256 * x + as.integer(DateTime[3])
x <- 256 * x + as.integer(DateTime[4])
x <- 256 * x + as.integer(DateTime[5])
x <- 256 * x + as.integer(DateTime[6])
x <- 256 * x + as.integer(DateTime[7])
x <- 256 * x + as.integer(DateTime[8])
x
```

Sure you can write this in a more elegant way. But I wanted the code to be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that'll work for my purposes.  Thank you!  Here's what I ended up with:

```
alongint <- function(hexarray){
  datain <- as.integer(hexarray)
  x <- datain[1]+datain[2]*256+datain[3]*256^2+datain[4]*256^3+
    datain[5]*256^4+datain[6]*256^5+datain[7]*256^6+datain[8]*256^7
  return(x)  
}

DateTime <- readBin(SERfile,"raw",size=1,8,endian="little")

x <- alongint(DateTime)
```

Comment: I am pretty sure it can be vectorized

Answer (score 0):

A first shot at vectorizing it (thanks for the idea):

```
xtoy <- function(a,b){
  return(a*256^b)
}

vxtoy <- Vectorize(xtoy,c("a","b"))
sum(vxtoy(as.integer(DateTime),c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)))
```